# What were the pre-Arabic Turkic words used for greeting?

Tags: turkic-languages

Most **Turkic languages** use the Arabic words for greeting, namely *salam*/*selam*/*merhaba* etc. The exceptions are Tatar *isänmesez* and Uighur *yakhshimusiz*, the origin of which I do not know. Are they Turkic? What did **Turkic** people say to greet each other before those Arabic words entered their vocabulary?

Comment: I downvoted and close-voted because language-specific questions are ruled out as off-topic by the definitions in the help center. That there is no Turkish site unfortunately doesn't make it on-topic here; there simply can't be an SE for everything. It might get on-topic if you can reword your question so as to be more about linguistics rather than usage, but "What did Turkic people say" isn't.

Comment: @lemontree  obviously it is not about specific language but about Turkic family and its historical development. It is as if one asked what was greeting in PIE.

Comment: @lemontree Thank you for stepping out and being honest. Anixx covered me well here. It is about Turkic languages, not Turkish spoken in the republic of Turkey. It is withing the field of **historical linguistics** as another language affected their vocabulary in the past. I did not ask for a translation, nor help learning (Anatolian) Turkish. Meanwhile the help center has the note **"and more"**. People ask questions about Chinese, Greek, Latin and PIE. What is the difference?

Comment: Sorry, I'm stupid - I actually confused Turkic with Turkish. Under this account you are right; I retracted my votes.

Comment: @It's cool, I understand! It is so easy to confuse it. :)

Comment: @jknappen: You should read carefully what I wrote and argue why it is off-topic. Instead you're being rude. Suggesting someone to start a new stackexchange site is outrageous.

Comment: @jknappen: That was not my original question, it was a comment. The original question is about tracing a word that in use in the **Turkic language family** before the influence of Arabic. It is a question that a person familiar with the Turkic languages and their history can answer. Therefore it falls under the category of historical linguistics. Nothing off-topic. Now please point out in the help center where it says that such a question is off-topic.

Comment: @jknappen: You press close for the question, not the commentary. That is simply abuse of the function.

Comment: If in doubt or hesitation, I read the commentatries, too: Maybe there is a good argument in either direction for the decision.

Comment: BTW, I doubt that the final question (What did Turkic people say to greet each other before those Arabic words entered their vocabulary?) is answerable at all: Greetings tend to follow some trends and fashions and are easily replaced over time. The ancient Roman greeting *Ave* cannot be reconstructed from modern Romance (but is preserved in the Latin literature, therefore we know it now).

Comment: @jknappen: Yes, but Turkic languages dispersed recently therefore it is not impossible that there's some kind of written account about it (e.g. by Chinese or Persians). Someone with expertise in Turkic language studies could confirm or refute this. In any case it would be satisfying for me, that is to say a) The word used for greeting was X or b) there is no account for how Turkic people greeted each other.

Comment: Agree, "the original word" assumes a discrete starting point and greetings evolve differently than other parts of speech.  It is probably more realistic to try and find the various words soon before the Arabic one in the various better-attested branches, eg Old Uyghur.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer : You have a point. I changed the word "original" to pre-Arabic.

Comment: @Midas I would also change "word" to "words" (and thus "was" to "were").  By the way I think that there is a high probability that the previous words were also foreign, given Sogdian (Iranic) influence, Chinese influence, Manicheanism and Buddhism in the first millennium.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer: Good points! done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The examples you gave are indeed Turkish, but they are not greeting words. Instead they are questions basically "How are you". You can say that in Turkish "Nasılsınız?".

The root *Esen* is used for greetings in old texts (Kutadgu Bilig, Divan-ı Lügati-t Türk), as more or less as it is used in modern Turkish *Esenlikler olsun*.

Comment: This is definitely the kind of answer I was expecting. I'll give some more time to the question before I select it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think the (modern) Uyghur word is cognate with Old Turkish yakış, Turkey-Turkish yahşı “good, pretty”.

Comment: thank you! However, I think you meant Azeri-Turkish, not Turkey-Turkish.

Comment: Ottoman Turkish according to Clauson. Also this: http://www.nisanyansozluk.com/?k=yah%C5%9Fi&x=0&y=0

Comment: Yahşi is still being used especially in Kayseri accent and Kars-Iğdır accents in Turkey. For the origin: http://kubbealtilugati.com/sonuclar.aspx?km=YAH%C5%9E%C4%B0%20%E2%80%93%20YAH%C5%9EI&mi=0

Answer (score 0):

Ar(y)ma - meaning "don't get tired".

Comment: Don't remove drive-by guest answers. Convert to a comment if possible.

Comment: The translation you gave is wrong. You can read my answer where I gave the correct phrase and translation.

Answer (score 0):

Kazakh language has similar constructs: Esenbısız? and Armısız?

Modern kazakh bloggers often use Armısız as greeting in place of arabic Assalamu-alaikum.

Armısız can be decomposed to Ar(honor) mı(question postposition) sız(you). The whole phrase literally means "Do you have honor?".

And "mı" in the middle of the construct signifies that this phrase came from ancient times because according to modern kazakh grammatics this phrase should be "Arsıŋız be?" where the question postposition comes last.

Example: https://youtu.be/JruUkasQHSg?t=48